# What is the percentage of unique words in a average document?

Tags: references, descriptive-statistics, text-mining

I am doing research for a data science class and am looking into the benefits of storing all unique words in a document along with the entire document.

I am looking for some research that has been published that averages the number of unique words in a document against the total number of words in a document.

I want to evaluate the added storage requirements when storing a list of unique words along with the original document versus the reduced search space when searching for words in a document.

Comment: It ought to depend on the type of document and document length.  Why not examine a sample of the documents you intend to process?

Comment: This was for a general case of a data storage where anybody could upload documents so samples cannot be acquired

Comment: Then you have no hope of obtaining any objective or well-supported answer: you will have to guess.

Comment: The information I was looking has been accepted as an answer

Comment: Yes--but it doesn't answer your question, does it?  It only tells you what you might expect the relationship between document length and number of words to be.

Comment: To begin with, I was hoping for a average number of "all documents". And you are absolutely right, without a sample I won't be able to get the true search space reduction but this is the closes I can get. I am going to make some sample sizes and try to show how the search space grows slower using unique words rather than the entire document as the document size grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap's law says the number of unique words in a document obeys a power law in the length of the document. For a document of length $n$, the number of unique words is $V_R(n)=Kn^\beta$ for some $K$ and $\beta$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaps%27_law